# Convert DF table to json by grouping a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below DF.

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|PAYMENT_TYPE       |TRANSACTION_TYPE |TRANSACTION_COUNT|
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|OFFLINE            |CHEQUE           |5                |
|ONLINE             |CREDIT           |135              |
|ONLINE             |DEBIT            |297              |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Have to group this into json string by grouping based on PAYMENT_TYPE. Any idea how to do this.

```
{"OFFLINE": {"CHEQUE": 5}, "ONLINE": {"CREDIT": 135, "DEBIT": 297}}
```

I have tried using the below

```
val data = res.groupBy($"PAYMENT_TYPE").agg(collect_list(concat($"TRANSACTION_TYPE", lit(":"), $"TRANSACTION_COUNT")).as("json_data")).show(false)
```

But able to get the below output but couldn't get the above output format

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+
|PAYMENT_TYPE       |json_data              |
+-------------------+-----------------------+
|OFFLINE            |[CHEQUE:5]             |
|ONLINE             |[CREDIT:135, DEBIT:297]|
+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Is the grouping the issue? Is it the JSON serialization? Provide us the code you tried and explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the solution below.

Same can be achieved using `udf` with json libraries in easy way.

`Note` - I have used multiple aggregated functions to achieve expected results & It might impact performance as well.

```
val df = """
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|PAYMENT_TYPE       |TRANSACTION_TYPE |TRANSACTION_COUNT|
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|OFFLINE            |CHEQUE           |5                |
|ONLINE             |CREDIT           |135              |
|ONLINE             |DEBIT            |297              |
+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
""".toDF
```

```
df.show(false)

+------------+----------------+-----------------+
|PAYMENT_TYPE|TRANSACTION_TYPE|TRANSACTION_COUNT|
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
|OFFLINE     |CHEQUE          |5                |
|ONLINE      |CREDIT          |135              |
|ONLINE      |DEBIT           |297              |
+------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

```
val mdf = df
.groupBy($"PAYMENT_TYPE")
.agg(
  collect_list(
    map(
      $"TRANSACTION_TYPE", 
      $"TRANSACTION_COUNT"
    )
  ).as("data"))
.selectExpr(
  "PAYMENT_TYPE",
  "reduce(data, map('', ''), (acc, e) -> map_filter(map_concat(acc, e), (k, _) -> k != '')) as data"
)
.groupBy(lit(1))
.pivot($"PAYMENT_TYPE")
.agg(first($"data"))
.drop("1")
```

```
mdf.show(false)
+-------------+-----------------------------+
|OFFLINE      |ONLINE                       |
+-------------+-----------------------------+
|{CHEQUE -> 5}|{CREDIT -> 135, DEBIT -> 297}|
+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

```
  mdf
    .select(
      mdf
      .columns
      .map(c => map(lit(c), col(c)))
      .reduce(map_concat(_, _))
      .as("json_data")
    )
  .select(to_json($"json_data").as("data"))
  .show(false)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"OFFLINE":{"CHEQUE":"5"},"ONLINE":{"CREDIT":"135","DEBIT":"297"}}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, thanks for the answer. Could you please let me know what version of spark are you using. We are having spark 3.3.0 and don't find reduce in that version. May be I have to use fold. I tried running this in 3.4.0 but getting error with reduce 

extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', ----

== SQL ==
reduce(data, map('', ''), (acc, e) -> map_filter(map_concat(acc, e), (k, _) -> k != '')) as data
------------------------------------^^^

Also, does pivot accept column name? I'm getting error saying the required should be String and not Column.

Thanks

Comment: I think I have used spark 3.5.0

Comment: Subba, will this solution is not worked ? if it works please accept as answer.